# Server side include issue. IIS 7.5

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7, server-side-includes

I'm migrating a `web server` to another server. Currently both `web servers` are working. They are using the same physical path. I have one of my sites (coded in `asp`) which uses server side includes for `asp`. The issue is that the old site is working fine in terms of `SSI`, however the new site is not. The new site is showing some code instead of loading the included file. I checked to make sure that all `IIS` settings are the same and everything looks the same. Appreciate your ideas to find out what else that I missed in `IIS` settings. (I assume the code is correct since it is working fine for the old server)

Comment: can you run a webpage on your new server? Something like localhost:port#

Comment: Yes I can run many sites in the new server. The only one that doesn't work properly is the one has includes on it

Comment: What is the extension of the included file ? If it is not .asp, can you try changing it to .asp ?

Comment: it is .asp @SearchAndResQ